# Castle Windsor config pointing to connectionStrings section in web.config

Tags: castle-windsor, connection-string

I want to inject a connection string into my repository but ideally, I want this connection string to be in my web.config connectionStrings section rather than in my windsor config. Is this possible?

I know I can use the fluent interface and achieve this easily but my bosses want an xml config file.

I also know that I can define a property and use that in my windsor config to pass the parameter in, but I have other code that reads the connectionstring from the web.config directly and do not really want two places with the same connectionString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244935/inject-app-settings-using-windsor) has a solution that's very similar to what you want
- You can tag the classes that need the connectionstring with an interface like this:

  ```
  interface IRequiresConnectionString {
      string ConnectionString {get;set;}
  }
  ```

  then you subscribe to the event `container.Kernel.ComponentModelCreated` (or write a `IContributeComponentModelConstruction`), inspect the component implementation type and if it implements IRequiresConnectionString you put the connectionString in the component's parameters.
- You can also do the above without the interface if you follow the convention that the connectionstring parameter will always be called `connectionString` (or whatever you like) but this is error-prone, if you accidentally name your parameter `conectionString` it would not get injected.

Comment: I would actually use `IContributeComponentModelConstruction` and convention to name the parameter 'connectionString' and write a unit test to verify I didn't screw that one up :)